# Is there a way to root multiple Android devices at the same time?

Tags: android, root, tablet

I need to root 20+ tablets, so I was curious if there is any way to root multiple android tablets at the same time.

Comment: Maybe a better fit for http://android.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can open heimdall or the compatible equivalent from the shell; you can make a bash script that opens the program, selects a device, file, and options, and opens another shell until 20 counts. Depending on the program and your macro Savvy, you can have new tabs, pipes, or screen sessions to do them all at the same time. unfortunately, I'm not that good, and I have no way to test it, so you would be on your own trying to write that script.

EDIT:

It would probably be easier on a linux box as device names are as easy as `/dev/ttyUSB(n-1)` or `/dev/sdxy` for hard drives It would probably be easy is C (I don't know C so I can't say for sure) relatively simple in GNU/BourneAgainSHell. The basic rooting process is 
Download Proper Drivers

```
su
cp ~/Downloads/(superuserapplication).zip /run/(devicename)/sdcard/(superuserapplication).zip
heimdall -i TeamWinRecovery.version.tar -o /run/(devicename)
```

And then reboot the device and push all of the hardware buttons at once. This brings you to the recovery OS, where you can root your phone with the superuser application you copied earlier.
Again, It isn't pretty and this guide will need some tweaking; especially for an undertaking such as this.

Comment: I am not an expert myself; what type of folks should be able to do this? Not an app dev, I assume? I feel like we need someone with hardware level programming background?

Comment: @eager_learner313 Not sure. I think that it would be difficult to remotely trigger a `telinit 6` especially if it needs to go into recovery mode, and even then, I'm not sure how to interact with a recovery interface  that is touchscreen based.

Comment: @eager_learner313 I would expect a developer to be somewhat familiar with scripting at least, it wouldn't be a horrible place to start, but some sort of *nix admin would likely be better at automating the task.

Comment: Thanks. On a unrelated note, how much does a build version matter to the functionality and where can I find the change logs for a particular build?

Comment: it depends on how different the builds are. If you are using software designed for 3; it is probably okay for 3.0.2.1 but not 10.3.0.2.1. http://tools.android.com/recent looks like a good place to start. If something in the major changes section says ([completely*] [re*[buil*, designed, 'vamped]]) it will be harder.